# Use Javascript for display logic Qualtrics?

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

I want to ask about display logic in qualtrics.
Case example:
I have a question that needed to show list of answer depends on another question. 
Here's the example algorithm:

```
Q1:
a
b
c

Q2:
if Q1 selected a --> show 1,2,3
if Q2 selected b --> show 4,5,6
if Q3 selected c --> show 7,8,9
```

with Qualtrics display logic, it will be easy to do it.

But in my case I have more than thousand list of option to work off. And it's definitely can't use normal display logic because it will takes weeks.

So is there any way we can do it more efficently? Like using javascript?

Is there any example similar to these case?

Thanks

Comment: _"But in my case I have more than thousand list of option to work off."_ What is the question list format? What is next question following `z`?

Comment: the question is a single answer. The next question will show only a few (10-20 option from thousands option) that triggered from previous answered choice

Answer (score 0):

Few people know that you can set [Answer Choice Display Logic](https://www.qualtrics.com/support/survey-platform/survey-module/question-options/display-logic/#SettingAnswerChoiceDisplayLogic) on individual Answer Choices! Exactly what you're asking for. In this way you'd write Q2 as follows:

Q2:
1 [Answer Choice Display Logic: Show only if Q1=a]
2 [Answer Choice Display Logic: Show only if Q1=a]
3 [Answer Choice Display Logic: Show only if Q1=a]
4 [Answer Choice Display Logic: Show only if Q1=b]
5 [Answer Choice Display Logic: Show only if Q1=b]
6 [Answer Choice Display Logic: Show only if Q1=b]
7 [Answer Choice Display Logic: Show only if Q1=c]
8 [Answer Choice Display Logic: Show only if Q1=c]
9 [Answer Choice Display Logic: Show only if Q1=c]

Still a lot of clicking, but no duplication of questions. Hope that helps...

Comment: hi FvP, "Still a lot of clicking" is exactly what I want to avoid. Cannot imagine how long I need to clicking thousand of option.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could write a JavaScript to hide answer options. However, an easier solution is to make the follow-up question separate questions with 10-20 answer options each, then use display logic on each follow-up question to only show the follow-up question that applies based on the answer to the first question.

Comment: Hi gibbons, thanks for your suggestion. But i think it won't solve the time consuming only to do those question. My goal was how to make it less consuming time, thats why i think using javascript will be easier because we can copy the similar codition for other condition. CMIIW

Comment: It would reduce the number of display logic conditions by a factor of 10 to 20 times. That is a pretty big time savings.  If you want to go the JavaScript route, write some code, then if you have issues with it, post it and ask for help.